# iOS WebService doesn't seem to be starting. Anyway I can find out if its doing anything?

Tags: ios, web-services

I have built a WebService to retrieve user specific reports using a PHP API. I am fairly new to this so I followed some tutorials and help pages to build the web service. It doesn't seem to run at all so I am thinking I stuffed up or just incorrectly put code in that didn't belong as I was following multiple tutorials etc to get the desired result.

here is the code for .m file of the web service:

```
#import "reportsTestViewController.h"
#import "ReportsDataObject.h"

@interface reportsTestViewController ()

@end

@implementation reportsTestViewController

@synthesize label;



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.tesg.com.au/allCustBuild.php"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection) {
        //connect
        label.text = @"connecting...";
    } else {
        //error
    }

}

-(void)setupReportsFromJSONArray:(NSData*)dataFromReportsArray{
    NSError *error;
    NSMutableArray *reportsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *arrayFromServer = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataFromReportsArray options:0 error:&error];

    if(error){
        NSLog(@"error parsing the json data from server with error description - %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else {
        reportsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(NSDictionary *eachReport in arrayFromServer)
        {
            ReportsDataObject *report = [[ReportsDataObject alloc] initWithJSONData:eachReport];
            [reportsArray addObject:report];
        }

        //Now you have your reportsArray filled up with all your data objects
    }
}

-(void)connectionWasASuccess:(NSData *)data{
    [self setupReportsFromJSONArray:data];
}

-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    //We check against table to make sure we are displaying the right number of cells
    // for the appropriate table. This is so that things will work even if one day you
    //decide that you want to have two tables instead of one.
    if(tableView == reportsTable){
        return([theReportsArray count]);
    }
    return 0;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if(cell)
    {
        //set your configuration of your cell
    }
    //The beauty of this is that you have all your data in one object and grab WHATEVER you like
    //This way in the future you can add another field without doing much.

    if([theReportsArray count] == 0){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"no reports to show";
    }
    else{
        ReportsDataObject *currentReport = [theReportsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [currentReport buildingName];
        // in the future you can grab whatever data you need like this
        //[currentPlace placeName], or [currentPlace placeDay];
    }
    return(cell);
}

@end
```

and the code for the .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface reportsTestViewController : UIViewController  <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{

    IBOutlet UITableView *reportsTable;
    IBOutlet UILabel *Label;

    NSArray *theReportsArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@end
```

I'm sure it's something really ignorant that i've done but after going back through help pages and tuts, i can't find what I did wrong.

Comment: Well first off going to this address `http://www.tesg.com.au/allCustBuild.php` doesn't send back any JSON, just supplies a 404 company website? Second doesn't seem that you are handling the NSUrlConnection delegate methods, maybe you didn't post them?

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't seem that you are handling the NSUrlConnection delegate methods, maybe you didn't post them?"

Comment: Have you implemented any of these methods? `https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html`

Comment: no, not that I am aware of. Where would I implement those methods?

Comment: http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are establishing your connection ok, but you are never handling any data that gets sent back. Once you create a connection you need to add the delegate methods to handle the data sent back by the connection.

As mentioned in some of the comments you also need to verify that your php page on the server is indeed giving you the information you expect. By logging out the data string as below in the -connectionDidFinishLoading you will be able to see any data sent back from the server for debugging.

```
//create an NSMutableData property in your interface
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *myDataIvar;

//initialize it when you create your connection
if (connection){
    self.myDataIvar = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    [self.myDataIvar setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [self.myDataIvar appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Connection Failed: %@", error.userInfo);
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    //this is where you would parse the data received back from the server
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.myDataIvar encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Received Data: %@",responseString);
    [self setupReportsFromJSONArray:self.myDataIvar];
}
```

This way at least you will be able to see what data you are receiving back from the server.

EDIT:
Also your test page does not seem to be putting out any json data. When I navigate to it all I get is "how". 
I put up a quick php page that you can use to test your obj-c code. It will echo back an array with 10 test results to fill your tableview if your code is correct.

```
//Create your request pointing to the test page
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.codeyouniversity.com/json_test.php"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];
```

If you want to put the php on your own page for testing this is what I used.

```
<?php
    $jsonArray = array('result1','result2','result3','result4','result5','result6','result7','result8','result9','result10');

    echo json_encode($jsonArray);
?>
```

Here's a link to Apples documentation for the URL loading system as well
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i

Comment: thanks for that, I see where that's headed. I tried your code and i got an error "invalid argument type 'void' to unary expression" on the didReceiveResponse method

Comment: Which line was it on? Oops, just saw you said where

Comment: Edited, try that version.

Comment: thanks i'll have to try this in the morning. I appreciate your help.by the way, the test page requires POST data from the login page to populate the SQL query. Im HOPING thats why its not working lol!!

Comment: glad to help. Good luck! Let me know if you need any more assistance. I just finished setting up two web service apps.

Comment: LOL just realised i dunno how to PM on here says i don't have enough rep to chat. I decided to stay up and keep working!! I have been fiddling with the code you gave me and i now have an error in the NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.myDataIvar]; line "No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'initWithData' how do I declare that?

Comment: Since you don't have enough reputation to chat yet, I'll keep this going here. I updated the code, I forgot to add the encoding to it.

Comment: ok so everything you put into that code worked good from what I can tell. The output stack now shows all of the JSON encoded data from the API. still nothing showing in table view though. I think I got confused with how it all works when i first built it because some of the names for the array wouldn't work. all of the tableView unchanged from my original post

Comment: Take a look at your arrays, you're adding your data from json to one array (reportsArray), and your tableData is looking for data in another array (theReportsArray).

Comment: yeh that's where i got confused. When i put the reportsArray name into the field it came up with an error saying "use of undeclared identifier 'reportsArray' however if I try to declare it it says "local declaration of 'reportsArray hides instance variable'. I did a quick search and must have got confused with the info i found so now i dunno where I am going wrong lol

Comment: ok so I am still stuck on getting info to show on my tableView. there are no longer any errors from my code (that's not to say it's correct though!!) the JSON data is coming up in the output stack so the connection to the API is working correctly. I have double checked the delegate and datasource is assigned correctly but I see no data in the tableView nor do I get any errors… Whats the best way to troubleshoot this??

Comment: It's fixed!! Turns out my problem was with my dataObject model. Thanks for your help DigitalHound. Now I gotta figure out the whole authentication thing. Time to start reading!!

Answer (score 0):

try this one if you get result, your url is wrong.I think now itself your url is wrong

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection) {
        //connect
        label.text = @"connecting...";
    } else {
        //error
    }

}
```

Comment: nope nothing, and there is absolutely nothing in the output stack. Maybe I'm not calling it properly. I seque to this viewController with a button, would that cause an issue?